# How to run a python file which is present outside the docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Inside VM I created a docker container, Now there are some python files present outside the container(present in host directory of VM) how can I execute these python files from container anyone help me with this

Comment: Mount them into the container.

Comment: [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) it

Comment: Ignore the container and run the `python` binary on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can copy or mount the python file inside the docker container then execute the python with CMD.

For ex:
`docker run -it -v myfile.py:/tmp/myfile.py python python /tmp/myfile.py`

Answer (score 2):

You should mount the vm directory like this:

```
docker run -d -it --name your-container-name -v /host/path:/usr/local/bin container:image
```

Also you must be sure /host/path permissions are propperly set.
[Volumes in docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Answer (score 0):

docker run -t -i -v <host_dir>:<container_dir>  ubuntu /bin/bash
By this command I'm able to access host directory by inside the container where the directories are mounted and can able to run python file present in host by container

Comment: Your answers will be more readable if you learn to format them properly.  See the other answers to this question to learn more.